# Django: access user information from a generic.view

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I am trying to access to the current user information to filter the client's items but  I am stuck with an error.

I guess must be a different way to request the information of the current user. I am using this: self.kwargs.request.user.

I got that error when using self.request.user I get this error get_context_data() missing 1 required positional argument: 'user'

My url.py

```
url(r'^update/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.CampaignUpdate.as_view(), name='update_campaign'),
```

AttributeError at 
'dict' object has no attribute 'request'

```
class CampaignUpdate(generic.UpdateView):
        model = Campaign
        fields = [.....]
        template_name = 'campaign/campaign.html'
        success_url = '../../'

        def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
            context = super(CampaignUpdate, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
            items = items.objects.get(client= self.kwargs.request.user)
```

Comment: Add full stack trace

Comment: @SardorbekImomaliev I changed  `def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):`  to this `def get_context_data(self, form_class=None, **kwargs):` and worked fine. I don't know why

Comment: @SardorbekImomaliev using `self.request.user`

Comment: Why would you change `get_context_data` methods signature? Show us your full view. I think you are using GCBV not in a right way.

Comment: @SardorbekImomaliev I want to generate an list with the items and send it  to the template to generate a autocomplete form

Comment: It doesn't answer the question. For this you shouldn't have needed to change method's signature. Why can't you just show us your view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed 
`def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):`

to

`def get_context_data(self, form_class=None,  **kwargs):`

and it worked fine, even though I don't know why...

Answer (score 1):

> Use the below code to get current user 'Item' object.

```
class CampaignUpdate(generic.UpdateView):
    model = Campaign
    fields = [.....]
    template_name = 'campaign/campaign.html'
    success_url = '../../'   


    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(CampaignUpdate, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['items'] = Items.objects.get(client= self.request.user)
        return context
```

> If you want to get the 'Campaign', you can just access line self.object as its a UpdateView

Comment: I got that error when using `self.request.user` I get this error get_context_data() missing 1 required positional argument: 'user'

Comment: Use this , context = super(CampaignUpdate, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)